# The vertical lines in my tabular environment are scattered

Tags: tables, rules

I'm using pdflatex and have some trouble: the vertical lines in my `tabular` environment are all scattered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| l | c | l |}
  \hline
  Abbreviation & Description & Relation\\
  2 & einstein & $E = m*c^2$ 
  \\\hline\\ 
  3 & pythagoras  & $c^2=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's probably connected to the formula inside the cell. Any help is greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Just FYI, it's generally considered a Really Bad Idea to use vertical lines in tables. I'm afraid I don't have the needed citation to hand at the moment, but I'm sure another user will step in to provide it.

Answer (score 2):

You need two ampersands to create columns in the empty line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| l | c | l |}
\hline
Abbreviation & Description & Relation\\
2 & einstein & $E = m*c^2$ \\\hline && \\
3 & pythagoras  & $c^2=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have provided a quick fix. See MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
{%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{| l | c | l |}
  \hline
  Abbreviation & Description & Relation\\\hline
  2 & einstein & $E = m*c^2$ 
  \\\hline
  3 & pythagoras  & $c^2=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\vspace*{1cm}
{%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{ l  c l }
  \toprule
  Abbreviation & Description & Relation\\
  \midrule
  2 & einstein & $E = m*c^2$ 
  \\
  3 & pythagoras  & $c^2=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```